# How to insert values from a php form to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a very simple php form that inserts values in a database.
First I have created a form :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>insertion de données en PHP :: partie 1</title>
  </head>
<body>
<form name="insertion" action="insertion2.php" method="POST">
  <table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr align="center">
      <td>nom</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nom"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>prenom</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prenom"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>adresse</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="adresse"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>code postal</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="codePostal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>numéro de téléphone</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="telephone"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="insérer"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I created a second php file with the mysqli database connection and a SQL query to insert the values in the database :

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "info");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Echec lors de la connexion à MySQL : (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $nom     = $_POST["nom"] ;
    $prenom = $_POST["prenom"] ;
    $adresse = $_POST["adresse"] ;
    $cp        = $_POST["codePostal"] ;
    $tel       = $_POST["telephone"] ;

    $sql = "INSERT  INTO personnes (nom, prenom, adresse, cp, telephone)
                VALUES ( '$nom', '$prenom', '$adresse', '$cp', '$tel') " ;

    $requete = mysql_query($sql, $base) or die( mysql_error() ) ;

    if($requete)
    {
       echo("L'insertion a été correctement effectuée") ;
    }
    else
    {
       echo("L'insertion à échouée") ;
    }
?>
```

But now I have errors :

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given
>   in C:\wamp\www\Inform\insertion2.php on line 20 Notice: Undefined
>   variable: base in C:\wamp\www\Inform\insertion2.php on line 20

and I don't know what to do. Can you help me?

Comment: Define `$base` ! Edit: Don't mix mysql_* and mysqli_*. Prefer mysqli_*.

Comment: Should i replace all mysql by mysqli?..

Comment: Yes. One reason: `Mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.`

Comment: You are also mixing OOP with procedural apis: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php If you stick with the OOP api, you would be writting something like `$res = $mysqli->query($sql);`

Comment: // replace to this // $requete = mysqli_query($sql, $mysqli) or die( mysql_error() ) ;

Comment: Also, sanitize your data before inserting into database

Comment: What do you mean by sanitize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing it up with `mysql`. Try with -

```
$requete = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die( mysqli_error());
```

Instead of -

```
$requete = mysql_query($sql, $base) or die( mysql_error() ) ;
```

Comment: Happy to help you.. Please upvote/accept the answer if it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you need to define your $base variable. 
You also call both mysqli and mysql functions.

Since you write it is a Mysqli database, you should use the mysqli functions at all times in your code.

But you really also should sanitize your parameters. This code is very much open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

You migth want to look into using mysqli->Prepare and execute with parameterized queries.